# Error is occurring, setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have the columns in my Data Frame as shown below:

```
 Venue             city                Venue Categories

  Madison         London      [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...,0,0]
  WaterFront      Austria     [0, 1, 1 0, 0, 0,  0, ....0,1]
  Aeronaut        Marvilles   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, ....1,1]
  Aeronaut        Paris       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ....1,1]
  Gostrich        New York    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ....1,0]
```

I am passing this data to my machine learning model , but `model.fit` is not accepting the input , My code is shown below , that I am trying ,

```
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
dff['Venue']=labelencoder.fit_transform(dff['Venue'])
dff['city']=labelencoder.fit_transform(dff['city'])
dff = dff[["city (S)","Venue Categories", "Venue"]] //reordering the columns
data= dff.iloc[:,:2]
labels=dff.iloc[:,-1:]
train_data,test_data,train_labels,test_labels=train_test_split(data,labels,test_size=0.20)
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(train_data,train_labels)
```

My target variable is Venue.The type of train data in above code is DataFrame  , I have changed into numpy array as well using `train_data=train_data.to_numpy()`, but all in vain. I don't know why it is occuring either is due to the Venue Categories column because it is in the list or something else.

Comment: Did you check if it might be because of you provide string as target? You may have to convert them to integer values for each string; 0 for Madison, 1 for WaterFront etc. **BUT** please share the error.

Comment: You should see my code first , I have label encoded my Venue column